# What is the Python <> operator

Tags: python, operator-keyword, python-2.x

What exactly is the `<>` operator in Python, and why is it undocumented (as far as I can tell)?

Is it the same as `!=` or `is not`?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: it is equivelent to `!=`

Comment: Tip: remember that you can find the built-in help for keywords and operators by passing a string to `help`, e.g. `help("<>")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators), `<>` is the same as `!=` (i.e. *"not equal to"*, rather than `is not` which is *"not identical to"*), but the latter is preferred:

> The comparison operators `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings of the same operator. `!=` is the preferred spelling; `<>` is obsolescent.

In 3.x, `<>` [has been removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) and only `!=` exists.

Comment: really you should never use `<>` anyway ... so aweful ... +1 all the same ofc

Comment: @JoranBeasley agreed, and I've added a supporting quote from the docs

Comment: I never knew `<>` existed and now it's gone. So sad.  `<>` is easier to type than `!=`. RIP. I'd have lamented you if I'd known you.

Answer (score 7):

It is documented, but you're not supposed to use it. Your guess about it being equivalent to `!=` is correct. Quoting the [**Python 2** documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`.

Then as part of the general cleanup of **Python 3**, the operator was [removed entirely](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> Removed `<>` (use `!=` instead).

---

#### Historical note

It goes back quite a long way; at least as far as **Python 1.4**. I found an entry in the [old docs](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node7.html):

> `<>` and `!=` are alternate spellings for the same operator. (I couldn't choose between ABC and C! :-)

The docs started recommending `!=` with Python 1.5.2p2.